# Exceptions inheritance in PHP

Tags: php

**Let's look this code:**

```
class customException extends Exception{}
$a;
try{
    if(!$a)
        throw new customException("Variable not initialize");
    echo $a;
}
catch(customException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Catch block work and we get the error text on the screen, but if i change this `catch(customException $e)` on `catch(Exception $e)` it will be work...why? We throwed exception on class `customException`, why it will be work?

Explain me pls

Comment: Exceptions bubble up. Basically all custom exceptions are simply exceptions at their core so it makes sense if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

`catch(exception $e)` does mean something like "catch `$e` if `($e instanceof exception)` is true.

`instanceof` checks are true for a class (e.g. `customException`), all their parents (e.g. `exception`) and all interfaces that the class or any of the parents implement.